# How to reassign a variable from another class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, class, object, kotlin

In the application that I'm building, in an Activity, I have an class that I used in diverse functions throughout my Activity.

```
class SelectChapterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val storyInfo: Story // the class
        get() {
            val storyTest = Gson().fromJson(intent.getSerializableExtra("storyJson").toString(), Story::class.java)
            return (storyTest)
        }
```

I need this class to be accessible from all the Activity, because from this class I launch another activity, get the result from this activity, and from this result change a parameter in the class. So I tried to change the result in onResultActivity, here's the code :

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val result = data!!.getIntExtra("nextChapterId", 0)
                println("result = $result")
                storyInfo.currentChap = result
                println("result still = $result")
                println("result in the class = " + storyInfo.currentChap)
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's the result :

```
I/System.out: result = 2
I/System.out: result still = 2
I/System.out: result in the class = 0
```

I tried to put the story Class in my onCreate function, and it worked great, I had no problem to reassign it, so I guess the problem comes from the fact that's it's declared in SelectChapterActivity class. My problem is that if it's in the onCreate function, I can't access it from onActivityResult.

So, given this, where does the problem comes from (technically) and how to fix it ?

Plus, is the way I choosed (put the class inside a class activity) a good way to do ? If not, how should I do ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have a getter that pulls data out of an ``Intent`` and creates a new ``Story`` instance from that (every time you access it) and returns it, so the only way to change that value would be to mess with the intent. Couldn't you just create your ``Story`` as a normal ``val`` or ``var``, and update it when you get some new data?

Comment: If you use a single Activity architecture with Fragments, you can load it in an Activity-scoped ViewModel and it will be accessible from all your Fragments and survive configuration changes. And if you need to persist its changes, you can initiate it from one place: the single Activity's `onStop()`.